# Terminal opens neovim instead of vim

Tags: vim, zsh, neovim

I use Ubuntu with the zsh shell, and when I try to open vim with the `vi` or `vim` command it opens neovim instead. I tried using the original bash shell, but it still didn't work. I tried `sudo update-alternatives --config vi` but it didn't work either.

Comment: When you installed neovim, it may have inserted itself as the preferred alternate in the alternatives list - run the command `update-alternatives --display vim` to check

Answer (score 0):

Try by using *update-alternatives* that let you choose which command to run among the alternatives:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config vi
```

Comment: Didnt work sadly but thanks

Comment: add that to the question please.